# Calling external class and methods

Tags: java, linux, terminal

To start off I am in the beginning stages of learning Java and I am working on different exercises.

One of the exercises gives me this external class: http://pastebin.com/g8hCTRCc

I need to write an application to Calculate and print the maximum and the minimum of two rational numbers defined in the program as variables.

So far I have imported the class (I believe correctly) but I have no idea how to call methods from there.

```
package Rational;
import Rational.add;
public class test {
  public static void add(String[] args){
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Create an instance of `Rational`. Call its methods. Which part is causing the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by creating an instance of the class using its constructor.  It appears most methods on the class only accept an instance of `Rational` as an argument, so a second instance of `Rational` must be created.  Pass the second instance of `Rational` into the `add()` method of the first, which will return a new instance of `Rational`.  All of this code should be included in a `main` method for execution.  The import statement should also be modified to exclude `add` since imports require a fully qualified class name, not a method on a class.

```
package Rational;
import Rational;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rational rational = new Rational(1,2);
        Rational rational2 = new Rational(1,2);
        Rational rationalTotal = rational.add(rational2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer and I've gotten this far before but figured I was doing something wrong because of the following errors: http://pastebin.com/8w2CMXpN

Comment: change `import Rational.add;` to `import Rational;`

Comment: @user2305262 Are you running this via the command line?  How is your project structured?  Does it have any packages?

Comment: I just have a root directory 'tmp'. Inside I have Rational.java, Rational.class & Test.java. The exercise specifically states "Note: when compiling the exercise files remember to keep the file Rational.class in the same directory, as the files with the solutions to the exercises." And yes, I am running it via command line.

Comment: If I remove the first 2 lines of code and add `System.out.println( rationalTotal );` It seems to be working... How is this right?

Comment: Okay, then you shouldn't have the `package Rational;` line in your code since its not packaged.

Comment: In that case it gives me an error [pastebin.com/K6zN8pJ8](http://pastebin.com/K6zN8pJ8). As I stated in a previous reply, if I remove lines 1 and 2 it seems to work.

Comment: @user2305262 Glad I could help. Did you figure it out?